# Reverse engineering Oracle database using Hibernate Tools in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, hibernate

I am using `Eclipse Luna` and have added the `Hibernate Tools`. I wanted to `Reverse Engineer` my `Oracle` database. I tried the same steps using `MySQL` and was successful.

I also tried `Revese Engineering` in `Netbeans` for my `Oracle` schema and was successful.

As I would like to develop my applications in the `STS` environment, I want to go with `Eclipse` or `Spring STS`. My tables were designed years before and are related to a legacy application that I would like to upgrade to `Spring`.

1. In the `Database Connections`perspective I can see my `Oracle` database and the schemas.
2. In the `Hibernate` perspective, I could generate my hibernate.cfg.xml file as below:
   http://pastebin.com/RDAmGukq

Here is the tutorial that I followed:
[*How to generate Hibernate mapping files & annotation with Hibernate Tools*](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/).

My problem is that in the `Hibernate Configurations` view I cannot see my Database. So if I try to proceed to generate the `hibernate.reveng.xml` it will generate an empty file, with no tables to generate my mapped POJOs.

What I can conclude is that my `Hiberbate Configuration` is failing.

Please help.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I came across was described in this tutorial:
[*How to Generate HBM (Hibernate Mapping) files and POJO (Model) Classes in Eclipse*](http://javafws.blogspot.com/2013/04/generate-hbm-files-pojo-classes-in-eclipse.html).

It worked fine. What I was doing wrong was to use the schema name in lower-case. It must be in upper-case.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.